# Excel: Find a specific cell and paste the value from a control cell into it

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have two columns one containing the room number, e.g. B-CL102, the other containing a varying integer.

I want to enter a different, manually determined, integer in a third column.

Whether by macro or worksheet function, is there a way to use two control cells at the top of the sheet, type the room number into one and the different integer matching that room into another.

I have minimal experience with macros essentially just the basics.

I tried to use a V-Lookup formula to look at the two control cells (Range) and then fill in the new column, however I don't know how to then fix that value so that it doesn't change when I change the values in the control cells.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible...don't know how. Are you set on that particular solution? Where are the numbers in your new column coming from? (There could be a better solution that doesn't involve macros at all, but I will refrain from suggestions until I know more.)

Comment: I'm unable to understand your question. Please post a sample to your question and expected answer. Please consider editing your question.

Comment: JongleurX no I am not set on using Macros, the new numbers are coming from me counting data points on a drawing. I am just trying to cut out some of the process. I tried to use a V-Lookup formula to look at the two control cells (Range) and then fill in the new column, however I don't know how to then fix that value so that it doesn't change when I change the values in the control cells thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if I've understood the question, but this macro may help. See below for screen shots to show what it does

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim row As Integer

row = 3

Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    If Range("A" & row).Value = Range("A1").Value Then
        Range("C" & row).Value = Range("B1").Value
    End If

row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Before I run the VBa

[image]

And after

[image]